# How to prevent sync of files from the root of Google drive folder

Tags: sync, google-drive, google-sync

I have the following issue:

I  only need to sync some folders from `google-drive` to one of PC:
[image: Screenshot of my env]
But there is a problem if I create any files(exactly files, not folders) in the root of `google-drive` they will be sync on this PC:
[image]

**Is there a way to prevent this behavior?**

Searching in settings and the Internet didn't get any useful results.

I've found only [this forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/KTqzPnO4xEo), but there was just reported the same behavior.

I understand, that I can keep all files in folders and didn't get messy the root of drive, but this behavior with sync settings was at least not obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there is not, as it says right there in your screenshots: "Files in Google Drive that are not in a folder will always sync."

[image]

Comment: But how to even find files "not in a folder"? There is no way to search for them in Google Drive!

Comment: @pete To find them you'd look at the root of your Google Drive.  Anything that's not in a sub-folder of your Google Drive folder is consider to be "not in a folder".

Comment: Thanks, but I see literally nothing in there at all (and I made sure I was on the right account); I only see folders, no top-level files. Yet, when de-selecting every single checkbox in Backup And Sync, it claimed I had 70 GB selected! Then when trying to actually sync to debug exactly what "files" it thinks I have, it just gets stuck forever "Preparing" hundreds of thousands of files! A quick internet search shows many people having the same problem